# Magnific popup to load HTML Link contents using iframe

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Need Magnific plugin help to solve my issue. Our third party developer developed a script to load as inline content. It works fine.

Now client required to load "html" contents using IFRAME when clicked the link. Not sure how to modify the existing JS file to add iframe type.

**JS code:**

```
TEST.overlay.initOverlay();

TEST.overlay = (function () {
    function Overlay() {
        var _this = this;
        this.initOverlay = function(){
            $('.popup-link').on('click', function(){
                var contentHTML = $(this).data('overlay-container');
                _this.open(false, $('.'+contentHTML).html(), $(this), {});
            });
        };


        this.open = function(modal, contentHTML, target, options ) {      
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                tClose: options.closelabel,
                tLoading: options.loadinglabel,
                modal: modal,
                preloader: false,
                midClick: true,
                mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                removalDelay: 300,
                closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
                items: {
                    src: contentHTML,
                    type: 'inline'
                },
                callbacks: {
                    open: function () {
                        target.trigger('overlayOpen');
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        target.trigger('overlayClose');
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        this.close = function() {
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        };

    }
    return new Overlay();
}());
```

**HTML** (Existing HTML structure for inline content)

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="popup-link" data-overlay-container="overlay-content-1">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/food/" alt="">
</a>
```

**HTML:** (Needed for IFRAME to load)

Have to call HTML files inside popup like inline container

```
<a href="test1.html" class="iframe-popup-link">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/food/" alt="">
</a>
```

Also please let me know how to define HTML structure for IFRAME container.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any more JS you can share? preferably all of the code that corresponds to test.popup

This code isn't tested but try changing the code inside this.open function to:

```
    $.magnificPopup.open({
                    tClose: options.closelabel,
                    tLoading: options.loadinglabel,
                    modal: modal,
                    type: 'iframe',
                    preloader: false,
                    midClick: true,
                    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
                    iframe: {
                      markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                  '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
              srcAction: 'iframe_src', // Templating object key. First part defines CSS selector, second attribute. "iframe_src" means: find "iframe" and set attribute "src".
          },
                callbacks: {
                    open: function () {
                        log('popup open');
                        target.trigger('popupOpen');
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        log('popup close');
                        target.trigger('popupClose');

                        if ($(target).parent().hasClass('slides-item') && $(target).parent().parent().find('.slides-item').length > 1) {
                            TEST.carousel.playCarousel($(target).parent().parent().parent().parent());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then the link to open the iframe would be:

```
<a href="http://www.linktowebpage.com" class="link-popup">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/food/" alt="Image">
</a>
```

Here is a fiddle of the code adpated to open a iframe http://jsfiddle.net/p90ysz80/2/

Comment: Hi Saunders.. Thanks for your reply. The code you shared have to put inside TEST.popup function? or need to create new function?  I updated the script with your code. But, iframe window not opening. I am very new to Jquery environment.

Comment: you just needed to replace the code you had with what i gave you. if it didnt work can you share all of your javascript so i can get a example working

Comment: Hi Saunders. Not sure whether its a good place to share the JS file. Is it possible to share JS file by mail or stackoverflow will block? I cant replace with the exist one. Because i need both inline content & iframe HTML loader. Thanks

Comment: you can edit your question and add information under your original question just put lots of ----- to seperate it

Comment: Sorry.. Just now checked the JS file. All scripts related to Magnific popup over;ay already pasted. Other than this "jquery-magnific-popup.js" default file was calling inside the template. No other JS files used to call. Thanks

Comment: There isn't any thing else relating to test.popup anywhere else? As that JavaScript is invalid when you run it by itself.

Comment: Hi Saunders... Sorry for late reply. Updated my question with all details you required. Now instead of iframe we plan to AJAX to call html file to load inside popup window. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fiddle to show code opening an iframe of a website

Comment: Hi.. Sorry to trouble you again. Implemented your code on HTML.. no issues. When we deploy on our CMS, trigger action (click function) on getting trigger. No event after click function not working. Links are directed to next page. Not sure why popup window not opening up.. Whatever code used in HTML are deployed to CMS. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: did you copy all of my code in? if you just replaced it you probably missed the `e.preventDefault()` which stops the link from going to the next page

Comment: Hi.. Sorry.. I already added preventDefault. It works fine in HTML version. Only thing in CMS.. we need to load this script after AJAX container loads.. I suspect our script loads before AJAX container loads. How to load our script after AJAX loaded? Thanks for your help

Comment: if you put an alert inside the click function does it alert? if it doesnt and its not binding to it try `$('.element').on('click', 'body', function () {});`

the body shoouldnt really be targeted its just i dont know your html and what is a constant element to be used - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Sorry again.. Saunders.. I m troubling you lot!! If i want to change same code to work on Ajax instead of iframe.. what are the modifications i need to do?? Requirement changed to AJAX by our client. As, getting some difficulty while integrating in CMS. Please.. one last disturbance!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have a look at this documentation - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax-type for ajax content

Comment: I try to use as per their documentation earlier. Sample HTML works fine. But, our website template not accepts basic and trigger with error. Thats why i thought whether we need to add some modifications to work on AJAX.

Comment: i dont understand your issue. you put the url of the file you want to use in the href and then remove iframe options form the plugin and change type to ajax. its quite simple if you read the documentation

Comment: Hi Saunders.. All issues are fixed. Finally its done!!... Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Saunders.. sorry to trouble you again. If i want to change type "ajax".. any codes need to modify? if i change and refresh the page.. 1st time loads fine.. 2nd time it loads 2 window(1 behind another).. 3rd time it loads 3 windows.  How to block this?

Comment: have you read the documentation on how to create a popup with ajax? if i was you. i would strip away all of this javascript and make a basic popup that does what you need and then bolt it back into the original js

Comment: Hi saunders.. sorry.. i fixed this issue on that day itself by modifying the code.. Forgot to reply you on this. As i am away from Internet last 5 days. Thanks